# mongoDB Error reading config file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, sudo

I can't start the mongo server. I'm running the following command

`sudo mongod --config /usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf`

I get the following error:

```
Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

If I run `mongo --version` I get the following:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2 git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 allocator: system modules: none build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Why can't I start the server?  I'm on macOS High Sierra

Comment: How did you install MongoDB? If you installed via Homebrew, the preferred way to start MongoDB is  `brew services start mongodb`  which will use a config file `brew` created at  `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`. If you want to start the server manually using `mongod --config ...`, you need to make sure a valid config file exists at the specified path. Your error message indicates a config file doesn't exist at `/usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf`. There is also no need to run `mongod` with `sudo` -- doing so is likely to create permission problems for you.